# getting mouse click screenX and screenY in as3

Tags: actionscript, actionscript-3

I want to get mouse click screen coordinates (by clicking outside AIR application window)

I tried the following, but i don't get anything, it seem like the ScreenMouseEvent.CLICK event not dispatched.

```
public function Main():void 
{   
if (NativeApplication.supportsSystemTrayIcon)//testExpression return true 
    {            
         SystemTrayIcon(NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon).
         addEventListener(ScreenMouseEvent.CLICK, click);
    }
}

private function click(e:ScreenMouseEvent):void 
{
      trace(e.screenX);//nothing displayed :(
}
```

Comment: I have never use the `ScreenMouseEvent` before, but it looks like it is only dispatched from the `SystemTrayIcon` Class. You might have to add your listener to that somehow.

Docs for ScreenMouseEvent: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/ScreenMouseEvent.html

Answer (score 0):

The `ScreenMouseEvent` is dispatched by the `SystemTrayIcon` only (Windows/Linux only). And the `SystemTrayIcon` instance (`DockIcon` for MacOs) is retrieved from `NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon`. 

So this is where you should attach your event listener, after specifying the tray icon graphic:

```
var sti:SystemTrayIcon = NativeApplication.nativeApplication.icon as SystemTrayIcon;
// Specifying an icon is obligatory on Windows - MacOs has a default icon
sti.bitmaps = [new IconAsset()]; // IconAsset = Embedded picture
sti.addEventListener(ScreenMouseEvent.CLICK, mouseClick);
```

Note that the resultant `screenX` and `screenY` properties of `ScreenMouseEvent` are confined within the icon area in the tray and not the whole desktop screen (Not surprisingly, since this is where you added the event in the first place).